# Screen saver just won't die in Mythbuntu after upgrade to 12.04

Tags: screensaver, mythbuntu

I have a computer dedicated to media playback which I just updated to version 12.04.

Since the upgrade, I just can't seem to get the screen saver to stop coming on while watching just about any kind of video.

I have of course opened System Settings -> Screensaver to try and turn it off. Whenever I do, I get this error message:

[image]

It doesn't seem to matter if I press "Cancel" or "OK". Either way, I get to the Screensaver interface settings where I put "Mode:" into "Disable Screen Saver". And yet, the screen turns black about 15 to 20 minutes into any video.

I looked for solutions on the web. I've tried this at the command line:

```
xset -dpms && xset s noblank && xset s off
```

Lastly, I found some suggestions for editing the /etc/X11/xorg.conf file. However, mine is completely blank, and it seems that if I put anything at all in there, it causes the X server to fail completely on boot.

How do I get my screensaver to be off and to stay off?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things you try

1. Verify you don't have gnome-screensaver installed

   `apt-get remove gnome-screensaver`
2. You could remove xscreensaver

   `apt-get remove xscreensaver`

You can also check in

`/home/USER/.xsession-errors`

and see if there is anything indicating why it may be broken (it's dying when trying to start).

A quick search shows an older post from 2009 with a similar issue. I've copied the relevant section of the same file from my Mythbuntu 12.04 machine below. You may want to check the same section in your file.

From /etc/xdg/xfce4/xinitrc

```
# launch a screensaver if enabled.  do not launch if we're root or if
# we're in a VNC session.
screensaver_enabled=`xfconf-query -c xfce4-session -p /startup/screensaver/enabled 2> /dev/null`
if test $UID -gt 0 -a -z "$VNCSESSION" -a "$screensaver_enabled" != "false"; then
    screensaver_type=`xfconf-query -c xfce4-session -p /startup/screensaver/type 2> /dev/null`

    case "$screensaver_type" in
        xscreensaver)
            xscreensaver -no-splash &
            ;;

        gnome-screensaver)
            gnome-screensaver &
            ;;

        *)
            if test x"`which xscreensaver 2>/dev/null`" != x""; then
                xscreensaver -no-splash &
            elif test x"`which gnome-screensaver 2>/dev/null`" != x""; then
                gnome-screensaver &
            fi
            ;;
    esac
fi
```

Comment: `apt-get remove xscreensaver` seems to have finally done the trick.

Comment: @dave I find it odd that removing xscreensaver package helped, since xscreensaver works only, if the daemon is running.